# How to Update only Quantity when products same

Tags: jquery, ajax

[image: img01] *01*

**when i add same product i want update only quantity**

[image: img02] *02*

[image: img03] *03*
[image: img04] *04*

This is my code :

```
   function addRow(product) {
    var qty = $('#qty').val();
    var code_chk = $(".code_chk").text();
    if ($('#procode_1').val() == code_chk) {

        var add_qty = $('#add_qty').text();
        v = ++add_qty;
        $('.set_qty').val(v);
    } else {

        sr++;
        $('#productlist').show();
        var $tableB = $('#productlist tbody');
        var $row = $(
            "<tr>" +
            "<td style='display: none;'>" + sr + "</td>" +
            "<td class='code_chk'>" + product.procode + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + product.prname + "</td>" +
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem, ideally add a snippet that reproduces it. As it is now, its mostly guesswork and noone would be able to help you out.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, attached image gives a little information about your DOM and code context. If you really need the answer, I'd suggest to start from editing your question and providing [wider](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) inputs.

Comment: Whats your expectation and what you get?

Comment: This is just a guess, but based on the small amount of code you have shared, I am suspecting that in the 2nd line `.text()` maybe returning the value as a string, so you may have to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to it. Additionally, I dont think you need `v= ++add_qty`, you could just do `add_qty += 1` instead, and then `$('.set_qty').val(add_qty);`

Comment: please guide ma check my code

Comment: please guide ma